# Matplotlib set axis limits works in __init__ but not on button click?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm writing a medium-sized application to review some data. The structure is that plots will be held in a QTabWidget interface, with a plot control widget to adjust x limits (and later, there may be more features in the control widget).  I have included a minimum reproducible example below.

Currently, I pass the axis of a figure to my control widget, and within that widget change the x limits after clicking a button. I have verified that the axis is being passed to the widget (with a print statement).  I can programmatically set the axis limits (see line 91: self.Fig_ax.set_xlim(5, 20000) ) in the widget __init__ function and it works, but in the button click function, that same syntax does not do anything.  However, with print statements, I verified that the axis is still being passed to the button click function.

I am very confused as to why the set_xlims method works in __init__ but not upon button press.  Use:  Run the code, enter a number in the X Min and X Max fields, click the Apply X Limits button. For the sake of the example, I hardcoded the button click axis shift to have defined limits rather than use what is entered into the fields, but those fields do get printed to the console for debugging purposes.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created 
"""


import sys

from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


## import matplotlib and animation
import functools
import random as rd
import numpy as np
from numpy import array, sin, pi, arange
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

## import threading
import time
from matplotlib.backends.qt_compat import QtCore, QtWidgets
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import (FigureCanvas, NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar)
## New:
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *

######################################################8

class AppWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'DDBRT'
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)

        self.DDBRT_Widget = DDBRT(self) # Call the DDBRT
        self.setCentralWidget(self.DDBRT_Widget) # set it as the central widget in the window

        self.show()
    ####
####
''' End AppWindow '''


# August 27 2019 Start building a custom QWidget that can be put into the tool in multiple instances to adjust xlims.  
# This may also serve as a templatge for other custom widgets that can go in


class XLimControlWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        # set layout:
        self.XLCWLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        # Insert X Min Box Label
        self.XMinSelectLbl = QLabel('Set X Min:')
        self.XLCWLayout.addWidget(self.XMinSelectLbl)
        # Insert X Min Entry Field
        self.XMinEntryField = QLineEdit('X Min')
        self.XLCWLayout.addWidget(self.XMinEntryField)
        # Insert X Max Box Label
        self.XMaxSelectLbl = QLabel('Set X Min:')
        self.XLCWLayout.addWidget(self.XMaxSelectLbl)
        # Insert X Max Box Entry Field
        self.XMaxEntryField = QLineEdit('X Max')
        self.XLCWLayout.addWidget(self.XMaxEntryField)
        # Insert Set Button
        self.SetXLimsBtn = QPushButton('Apply X Limits')
        self.XLCWLayout.addWidget(self.SetXLimsBtn)

        # Adjust layout so this widget is compact:
        self.XLCWLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.XLCWLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
            # Note, that doesn't actually work and it still looks ugly
            # That's annoying, but not worth figuring out how to fix right now.  
            # Need to focus on programming the behavior.

        # Try out the kwargs pass to make sure passing something works.
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            print('%s = %s' %(key, value))
        ####

        self.Fig_ax = kwargs['Fig_ax_Key']
        print('self.Fig_ax = %s of type %s' %(self.Fig_ax, type(self.Fig_ax)))
        # Try the fig ax set xlim, which does work but doesn't.
        self.Fig_ax.set_xlim(5, 20000)

        self.SetXLimsBtn.clicked.connect(self.SetXLimsBtnClkd)
    ####    

    def SetXLimsBtnClkd(self): # Define what happens when the button is clicked.
        self.xmin = float(self.XMinEntryField.text())
        print('X Min will be ', self.xmin, ' of type ', type(self.xmin))
        self.xmax = float(self.XMaxEntryField.text())
        print('X Max will be ', self.xmax, ' of type ', type(self.xmax))
        print('self.Fig_ax = %s of type %s' %(self.Fig_ax, type(self.Fig_ax)))
        self.Fig_ax.set_xlim(20, 45)                
        # End desired goal:
        # self.Fig_ax.set_xlim(self.xmin, self.xmax)

    ####
####        


class DDBRT(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        #%% Set up multithreading
        self.threadpool = QThreadPool()  # Set up QThreadPool for multithreading so the GIL doesn't freeze the GUI
        print("Multithreading with maximum %d theads" % self.threadpool.maxThreadCount())

        #%% Layout:

        ## Set layout
        self.MainLayout = QGridLayout(self)
        ## Create and embed CheckBox Placeholder
        self.ChkBx_Placeholder = QCheckBox('ChkBxPlcholdr1');
        self.MainLayout.addWidget(self.ChkBx_Placeholder, 3, 0)

        ## Create and embed tab container to hold plots, etc.
        # Initialize tab container
        self.TabsContainer = QTabWidget()

        # Initialize tabs
        self.tab0 = QWidget()

        # Add tabs
        self.TabsContainer.addTab(self.tab0, "Tab 0")


        # Populate 0th tab
        self.tab0.layout = QGridLayout(self)
        self.pushButton0 = QPushButton("PyQt5 button")
        self.tab0.layout.addWidget(self.pushButton0)
        self.tab0.setLayout(self.tab0.layout)

        # Add TabsContainer to widget
        self.MainLayout.addWidget(self.TabsContainer, 3, 1) # self.MainLayout.addWidget(self.TabsContainer, 2, 2) # Works just fine too, but I can worry about layout finessing later because it's not that difficult, important, or urgent right now
        self.setLayout(self.MainLayout)


        #%% Plot XLs (accelerations)

        XL_t = np.arange(0, 200000, 1)
        XL_X = np.sin(XL_t/20000)
        XL_Y = np.sin(XL_t/2000)
        XL_Z = np.sin(XL_t/200)


        self.tab8 =  QWidget()
        self.TabsContainer.addTab(self.tab8, "Tab 8: Acceleration mpl subplots")
        self.tab8.layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.XL_Fig = Figure()

        self.XL_X_ax = self.XL_Fig.add_subplot(3, 1, 1)
        self.XL_X_ax.plot(XL_t, XL_X)
        self.XL_X_ax.set_title('Acceleration X')
#        self.XL_X_ax.grid(True)
        self.XL_X_ax.set_xlabel('Time (s)')
        self.XL_X_ax.set_ylabel('Acceleration')
#        
        self.XL_Y_ax = self.XL_Fig.add_subplot(3, 1, 2, sharex=self.XL_X_ax)
        self.XL_Y_ax.plot(XL_t, XL_Y)
        self.XL_Y_ax.set_title('Acceleration Y')
#        self.XL_Y.grid(True)
        self.XL_Y_ax.set_xlabel('Time (s)')
        self.XL_Y_ax.set_ylabel('Acceleration')
#      
        self.XL_Z_ax = self.XL_Fig.add_subplot(3, 1, 3, sharex=self.XL_X_ax)
        self.XL_Z_ax.plot(XL_t, XL_Z)
        self.XL_Z_ax.set_title('Acceleration Z')
#        self.XL_Z.grid(True)
        self.XL_Z_ax.set_xlabel('Time (s)')
        self.XL_Z_ax.set_ylabel('Acceleration')
#
        self.XL_Canvas = FigureCanvas(self.XL_Fig)
        self.XL_Canvas.print_figure('test')        

#        # Create an XLPlot container widget and add the canvas and navigation bar to it
        self.XL_PlotContainer = QWidget()
        self.XL_PlotContainer.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.XL_PlotContainer.layout.addWidget(self.XL_Canvas)
        self.XLMPLToolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.XL_Canvas, self)
        self.XL_PlotContainer.layout.addWidget(self.XLMPLToolbar, 3)
        self.XL_PlotContainer.setLayout(self.XL_PlotContainer.layout) # Looks redundant but it's needed to display the widgets        



        # add XLPlotContainer Widget to tab
        self.tab8.layout.addWidget(self.XL_PlotContainer, 1)
        self.tab8.setLayout(self.tab8.layout)


        # add XLCWidget to tab
        self.kwargs = {"Fig_ax_Key": self.XL_X_ax}
        self.XLXLCW = XLimControlWidget(self, **self.kwargs)
        self.tab8.layout.addWidget(self.XLXLCW)    
    ####
####

#%%
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = AppWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I expect the button click to change the axes on all subplots (since I linked the subplots when I set them up), but the x limits do not change at all.  The button click function *does* run, as shown by the print statements.

Comment: Maybe you just forgot to redraw the figure after making changes to it?

Comment: No, when I make the change in the __init__ function, it affects the window size.  I could change         self.Fig_ax.set_xlim(5, 20000) to         self.Fig_ax.set_xlim(0, 1)  to demonstrate that in the extreme.

Comment: Well, yes, please demonstrate the issue with a runnable, self-contained code ([mcve]).

Comment: Keep in mind code can be rather persnickety and while it might let you dot your t's and cross i's besides seeing double you might get other odd results that you did not expect to occur which can be confusing especially if the program does not crash in the process

Comment: ImportanceOfBeingErnest : The code I provided is a minimal reproducible example .  The line 
       self.Fig_ax.set_xlim(5, 20000)      demonstrates that the figure axis can be changed; the line         self.Fig_ax.set_xlim(20, 45)     demonstrates that it can't be changed by a button click.

Comment: Dennis Jensen:  When I tried your suggestion, I got the error:  "TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type" .  So since XLimControlWidget is a QWidget, it has to super(QWidget)

Comment: I understand code can be persnickety, and I'm especially not extremely familiar with PyQt5 (or Python in general), so I was wondering if anyone could help pinpoint why it's behaving this way.  I'm coming from years of Matlab as my primary language, and a bit of C++.  Python seems to have different "rules" it follows.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, my apologies for not understanding your suggestion at first.  I've tested my code more and confirmed that the problem has to do with not re-drawing the figure after making changes to it.
Since I built this as a control module, I would rather not re-draw the entire plot, and just have it refresh after the button click changes the axes (I confirmed it changes the axes without updating the figure by combining print and get_xlims).

How would I re-draw the figure without having to do all the plotting and embedding in the QTabWidget again?

Comment: `canvas.draw_idle()`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, wonderful, thank you for the help!  It's working now.  I passed the entire figure to my control widget, used a = self.Fig.get_axes() to get a list of my axes, and a[0].set_xlim(20, 200) ;  self.Fig.canvas.draw_idle() to update the figure with the button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else finds this question later, here is the solution that worked:  I passed the entire figure to my control widget, used a = self.Fig.get_axes() to get a list of my axes, and a[0].set_xlim(20, 200) ; self.Fig.canvas.draw_idle() to update the figure with the button click.